# table row hover highlighting with Tablesorter / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery Tablesorter with the zebra widget for my table.

I want to be able to hover each row and change the background for the highlight.  Is this possible?  Anyone with ideas?

thanks.

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $rows = $('table tbody tr');
$rows.hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("rowHover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("rowHover");
});
```

Then create the stylesheet rule for zebra rows being hovered:

```
.even.rowHover,
.odd.rowHover {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```